# How do I handle button clicks in a custom Notification

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

I'm attempting to make a custom notification with a button using a `RemoteView`, which will perform an action without closing the notification drawer, similar to the way media clicks work. I am able to generate a custom notification using the following code:

```
public void setListeners(final RemoteViews view){

    //Opens up an activity, closes the notification drawer, and performs the action

    Intent skip = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReturnSlot.class);
    skip.putExtra("DO", "Skip");
    skip.putExtra("remoteview", view);
    PendingIntent btn2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, skip, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.skip, btn2);

}

public void setAsUpdate(){

    remoteView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.test);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.content, "This is some text");
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.name, "The Title");

    NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.temparrowicon);

    setListeners(remoteView);
    nBuilder.setContent(remoteView);

    int mNotificationId = 1;
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager)     getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, nBuilder.build());

}
```

Along with the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#000000">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#00bbff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/name" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/test"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/test" />
```

It displays a notification with a button, but i am unable to use the button without opening an activity, which will close the notification drawer. Is there a way to perform an action without closing the notification drawer like when clicking media?

All help is appreciated.

Some id names may be incorrect due to editing.

Comment: instead of getactivity use getbroadcast and create a broadcast receiver